# How to create a form with two vertically divided sections

Tags: html, css, forms

I am currently trying to create a basic form using HTML & CSS. In it there are 4 fields: amount of men, amount of women, amount of kids and amount of beer per adult.

I want the first three inputs to be on one side, and the fourth to have its own space on the right. I have not been able to achieve this effect. The beer field should be centered horizontally to the right, and beneath it, the input box.

Maybe I should be using a table for this but alas, I am very new to CSS and am honestly a bit clueless.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#app {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  padding: 1.5em;
  width: 30em;
}

#left-div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

#left-div input {
  width: 2em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

#left-div label {
  margin: 0.5em 0em 0.5em 0em;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Chopp */

#div-chopp {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#div-chopp label {
  display: block;
}

#div-chopp input {
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <form action="POST">
    <div id="left-div">
      <label for="men">Men</label>
      <input type="number" value="0" name="men">
      <br>
      <label for="women">Women</label>
      <input type="number" value="0" name="women">
      <br>
      <label for="kids">Kids</label>
      <input type="number" value="0" name="kids">
    </div>
    <div id="div-chopp">
      <label for="beer">Litros de Beer por Adulto</label>
      <input type="number" value="0" name="beer">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: No, don't use a table. Spend a bit of time looking at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox.

Comment: @isherwood exactly what I needed.

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start. You could use more custom classes instead of the descendant selectors. Avoid using IDs, though, so your CSS is reusable.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  padding: 1.5em;
  width: 30em;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.wrapper>div>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper>div:last-child>div {
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper input {
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <form action="POST">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div>
        <div>
          <label for="men">Men</label>
          <input type="number" value="0" name="men">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="women">Women</label>
          <input type="number" value="0" name="women">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="kids">Kids</label>
          <input type="number" value="0" name="kids">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>
          <label for="beer">Litros de Beer por Adulto</label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input type="number" value="0" name="beer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```